# What's correspondence between the model theoric and the set theoric kernel of homomorphism?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions, soft-question, model-theory

A kernel of a mapping $h$ from $\mathfrak{A}$ to $\mathfrak{B}$, generally,  is an equivalence relation $\{(a,a') \in \mathfrak{A} \times \mathfrak{A} \mid  h(a)=h(a')\}$.

However, in model theory, there is another version of definition of kernel of mappings. That is,
$\ker(h) \colon=\{\varphi(\bar a) \mid \models_{\mathfrak{B}}\varphi[h(\bar a)]\}$, in which $\bar a$ is a non-repetitive enumeration of $\mathrm{dom}(\mathfrak{A})$, $\varphi(\bar a)$ are all atomic sentences.

Let's call the former one set theoric version, the later one model theoric version.

My question: What's relationship between them? Are they equivalent to each other in some senses?

---

Elaboration for the model theoric version

The model theoric version I found was in exercise 1.5.4 in Hodges's Model Theory. This exercise mainly requires a proof of those assertion following are equivalent to each other:

(a) $\mathrm{diag}^+(\mathfrak{A}) \subseteq T$ and $T$ is =-closed;

(b) $T$ is the kernel of some homomorphism from $\mathfrak{A}$ into $\mathfrak{B}$;

(c) $T$ is the kernel of some surjective homomorphism from $\mathfrak{A}$ into $\mathfrak{B}$;

In which $T$ is a set of atomic sentences of $L(\bar a)$.

Since I haven't found an explanation why he defined kernel in this way, I asked this question here.

Comment: I don't think I understand the notation in the second one. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @tomasz Okay, I have clarified my post.

Comment: Don't use `|` for the set builder bar. Note that it leaves no horizontal space around it. Use `\mid` instead. If you want something that you can use with `\left`, `\middle` and `\right` then things get more complicated. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5502/how-to-get-a-mid-binary-relation-that-grows

Comment: @kahen Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

If the $ker_m(h)=diag(A)$, then the $h$ is an embedding and viceversa(see diagram lemma in hodges book). Hence, $ker_m(h)\neq diag(A)$ iff the set-kernel has a equivalence-class with more then 1 element.

Comment: Thank you for answering and sorry for late commenting as I'm in traveling yesterday. I have a question: do you mean $ker(h)$ the set-theoric kernel if $h$? If so, then $ker(Id_{\mathfrak{A}})=Id_{\mathfrak{A}} \ne \emptyset$ whenever $\mathfrak{A}$ is not empty, but $Id_{\mathfrak{A}}$ is an automorphism, hence an embedding. Thus $\ker_m(Id_{\mathfrak{A}})=diag(\mathfrak{A})$ but $ker(Id_{\mathfrak{A}}) \ne \emptyset$ in cases $\mathfrak{A}$ is not empty...

Comment: Okay, it is right now.